# Will SIVB ever become tradeable again?

Tags: stocks

As you may know trading of SIVB shares is currently halted. I have two questions regarding this:

- Is there a way to sell your existing shares right now? Even for for next to nothing?
- Will the stock ever become tradeable again?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on what you consider "tradable". It looks like SIVB will be delisted and will start trading on the pink sheets (OTC) under a new ticker.

> Following the removal of the Common Stock and Registered Depositary Shares from listing and registration on Nasdaq, the Common Stock or Registered Depositary Shares may then be immediately eligible to be quoted on the OTC Pink Quotation System. To be quoted on this system, a market maker must sponsor the security and comply with SEC Rule 15c2-11 before it can initiate a quote in a specific security. If the Common Stock or Registered Depositary Shares are delisted from Nasdaq, there can be no assurance that a market maker will apply to quote the Common Stock or Registered Depositary Shares or that the Common Stock or Registered Depositary Shares will be quoted in the OTC Pink Quotation System.

https://www.sec.gov/ix?doc=/Archives/edgar/data/0000719739/000119312523073665/d485308d8k.htm

> Effective March 10, 2023, the National Securities Clearing Corporation (“NSCC”) will no longer accept
> SIVB exercise and assignment activity for settlement. As a result, all exercise and assignment activity for
> SIVB options beginning March 10, 2023 will be subject to broker to broker settlement. It is unknown if and
> when SIVB shares will be eligible for settlement through NSCC again.
> The deliverable for SIVB options contracts will remain the underlying 100 SIVB Shares.

> If it is not possible for the
> delivering Clearing Member to effect delivery of the SIVB shares on the designated settlement date, then
> the settlement obligations of both delivering and receiving Members shall be delayed until such time as
> OCC designates a new exercise settlement date, settlement method and/or settlement value. This
> determination allows delivering Members the opportunity to effect settlement if they have SIVB shares and
> are able to effect delivery but delays the settlement obligation when this is not possible. Both the
> delivering and receiving Clearing Members are required to immediately notify OCC if they are unable to
> effect settlement.

> Pursuant to customary OCC broker to broker settlement procedures, inability to effect delivery may
> subsequently occasion cash settlement as determined by OCC.

https://infomemo.theocc.com/infomemos?number=52107 (PDF)

Answer (score 0):

Old Stone Bank (headquartered in Providence, RI) collapsed in the early 1990s (this Wikipedia article (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Old_Stone_Bank) says the collapse was in the 1980s, but I know I got a loan from them in the spring of 1992).

Shares in OSB traded several years after the Feds closed the bank - basically by people betting on the result of a lawsuit against the Federal government.  There's basically no value in Silicon Valley Bank right now.  I wouldn't hold your breath.